# Do programs somehow run differently for the root user, than for a non-super-user?

Tags: permissions, python, cron, vpn

**TL;DR:**
Will my custom Python programs run normally on Ubuntu 18.04 if I only use the root user? I'm just looking for reassurance; people and articles scare me into not using the root user, but it's inconvenient in my case. I'm the only person who will ever VPN into these remote IoT gateways, so there's no need for multiple users. I'll just login as root@ip-address every time, and schedule them to run using the root user's crontab.

**Background**
For my custom Python IoT applications, sometimes I need super-user privileges, for instance when I need to kill a process or reboot. However, some of my IoT gateways use Ubuntu, and some use OpenWrt or Yocto Linux. Those other non-Ubuntu gateways do not even have "sudo" installed, since they only have one user (root). This makes programming more complicated, since I have to check the OS and then prepend "sudo" to the command if it's an Ubuntu 18.04 OS... I think I could avoid that if I only used the root user on Ubuntu as well.

I'm just wondering if I should expect any nasty surprises if I only use the root user on Ubuntu 18.04... Would my programs run differently somehow? I don't think so, but I'm wanting reassurance... Thanks!

Comment: It mainly has to do with how security protocols are implemented on diff linux systems. Ubuntu rather you stay away from using root directly and in all cases in case something goes wrong but if you know what your doing then you can use the root user for your tasks. No surprises other than the "I told you" scenario that Ubuntu is trying to protect you from! Note from my experience using the root user means no limitations what so ever and that is indeed dangerous but again if you know what your doing then go ahead but do read about the reason Ubuntu used this security protocol!

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeUdosen. You've reassured me that my programs will run the same with 'root'. I have been reading lots, and the "principle of least privilege" makes sense. It also makes you think twice before using sudo. But mine are automated Python programs anyway, not actual users doing stuff ad hoc.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be anything different with root user. I'd be more focused on OS-specific differences. Does your application configure network interfaces in any way ? Ubuntu and OpenWRT differ in that regard. Does your app use package manager ? Does it call any external apps like /usr/bin/find ?

Comment: Thanks fellas! I did find one difference. "sudo /usr/bin/python3" could not find the libraries/packages pip3 installed without sudo. I reinstalled these packages with "sudo /usr/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt" and now the root user's python3 could find them.